store available disks for LVM in array
I am using lsblk command to get the device names on linux servers. However, I want to find the command that will help me scan the devices and store the results in an array only for devices that are not currently in use for LVM
Right now, I am using
lsblk -o NAME,TYPE,MOUNTPOINT | grep disk | awk '{print $1}'

However, this prints all the devices that are available and busy.
I need to print sd* device name that is available (not already in use) to perform LVM steps. I am trying to scan all the available sd* devices at run-time and based on availability mount the filesystems on the available sd* device

What exactly do you mean by not currently in use for LVM? Like block devices not pvcreate'd? Or PVs not belong to a VG? Or LVs that are not mounted? perform LVM steps What steps?

Technically LVM can run on any block devices, not only disks but also partitions, volumes (ZFS, Btrfs…), device-mapper devices (LVM, LUKS, RAID…) so here I assume you want to get full disks that are unpartitioned and completely unused by device-mapper. It's very tricky to cover all the possible results because there are many edge cases like zram, ramdisk, loopback, mtdblock, emmc, VM-direct-access disk… which are also block devices with a possible mountpoint and some of them may even identify as disks. But for most intents and purposes you can filter out the ones that are used by device mapper with dmsetup ls --tree or dmsetup deps, then filter out devices that are mounted or have a child that's mounted like this
deps=$(sudo dmsetup deps | sed -E -e 's#^.+[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]+dependencies[[:space:]]+:[[:space:]]+##g' \
                                  -e 's/\(([[:digit:]]+), ([[:digit:]]+)\)/-e \1:\2/g')
disksUnusedByDm=$(lsblk -o MAJ:MIN,TYPE,PATH | grep -v $deps | grep -P '^\s*\d+:\d+\s+disk' | awk '{print $3}')
freeDisks=()
for disk in $disksUnusedByDm; do
    if [[ "$(/usr/bin/lsblk -no MOUNTPOINT "${disk}" | grep -vE "^$")" == "" ]]; then
        freeDisks+=("${disk}")
    fi
done
echo "${freeDisks[@]}"

Actually you can get disks that are being used by LVM with pvdisplay and lvdisplay. Unfortunately the output PV/VG/LV names are somehow missing a dash compared to the device name so dmsetup is still more correct and versatile

Thanks @Phuclv, I changed PATH with NAME as path - it threw an error - unknown argument. Rest it is working as expected. I appreciate your help

@user312307 because PATH is required for the next lsblk -no MOUNTPOINT command to work, it doesn't work with only NAME. You can convert PATH to name later if necessary

There is an observation that it is skipping sdc as part of line 2 of this script. Where it is lsblk -0 MAJ:MIN, TYPE, PATH and I see that it has 8:32 disk /dev/sdc in the output but when it does grep -v $deps, it should print /dev/sdc as it is not in $deps and anything that is not matched should be printed as per grep -v logic. Not sure why it would skip that

I figured out the issue, we need to quote "$deps" in line 2 and it works fine.

No that won't work because I deliberately let the word splitting to work so that I can use -e for each dependency, because we can have a lot of dependencies for a device. You can see -e \1:\2 in the sed command. You can use the grep -E "dep1|dep2|...|dep3" which will work with quoting, but you'll need to modify the sed command
